# (ANDROID - CORDOVA) I wonder if it is possible to develop and use a native screen in a project

Tags: android, cordova

Hello There is something I want to make in an Android app developed with Cordova, but I am writing this because I have no idea if it is possible or how to do it.

I have an Android project based on Kotlin using Cordova.
When the app is run, loadUrl (launchUrl) is called from MainActivity, which inherits CordovaActivity then webView goes to launchUrl.
then with cwv = (super.appView.engine.view as WebView)

Basically, I believe it is no different from the Android structure created by Cordova.

What I'm curious about is adding a native bottom navigation bar(or it could be a drawer) and switching frameLayout by nav bar and control webView(Replaces calling with a web view engine) or other native fragments

i tried add menu without layout xml file on MainActivity

```
val bottomNavigationView = BottomNavigationView(this)
        bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_navigation)

        val layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        layoutParams.gravity = android.view.Gravity.BOTTOM

        val rootView = findViewById<FrameLayout>(android.R.id.content)
        rootView.addView(bottomNavigationView, layoutParams)
        
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.ic_document -> {
                    Log.d("1", "1")
                    true
                }
                R.id.ic_person -> {
                    Log.d("2", "2")
                    true
                }
                R.id.ic_settings -> {
                    Log.d("3", "3")
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
```

and menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_document"
        android:title="document"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_assignment_24"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_person"
        android:title="Person"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"/>
</menu>
```

but it seems didn't work properly I think it's because it uses Cordova's webview engine rather than loading the webview widget on the layout..

heres my cdv-gradle-config

```
"MIN_SDK_VERSION":24",
"SDK_VERSION":33,
"COMPILE_SDK_VERSION":34,
"GRADLE_VERSION":"7.1.1",
"MIN_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION":"33.0.2",
"AGP_VERSION":"7.1.1",
"KOTLIN_VERSION":"1.8.0",
"ANDROIDX_APP_COMPAT_VERSION":"1.3.1",
"ANDROIDX_WEBKIT_VERSION":"1.6.0",
"ANDROIDX_CORE_SPLASHSCREEN_VERSION":"1.0.0",
"GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION":"4.3.8",
"IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_GOOGLE_SERVICES_ENABLED":false,
"IS_GRADLE_PLUGIN_KOTLIN_ENABLED":false,



Please help me if this is possible or if it is possible but better to choose native or some other way thank you
```